# Getting form html and its values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Consider this html:

```
<form onsubmit="alert( $(this).html() );return false">
    <input type='text' name='test'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

If I type some text in the input box, the value isn't captured by html(). How do I get the raw form html and its input values?

Answer (score 3):

The `value` attributes etc are not synchronized with the form elements. You could use code like this though assuming your form only contains input which have a proper `value` (e.g. no select, checkbox and radio elements)

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':input', this).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('value', $this.val());
    });
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Don't forget to remove the `onsubmit` code from the HTML. If you have more than one form, replace `$('form')` with `$('#someid')` and add `id="someid"` to your form tag.

Comment: +1 Well answered, I was just trying to get the same approach working myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, $this.attr('value', $this.val()) doesn't add the "value" tag to an input element, at least in FF.

Comment: Hrm, sounds like jQuery does some custom handling for `value`. In this case, try `this.setAttribute('value', $this.val());`

Answer (score 0):

using Jquery, you can do like this

```
<form id='form'>
    <input type='text' name='test' id='name'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

and jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        alert($(this).find("#name").val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tsegay/yJaHh/1/)